# How to use dput() to create code necessary to create whole of iris dataset as JSON

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

If the first 38 rows of `iris` dataset are converted to JSON, then provided to `dput()`, the resulting text in the R console can be copy/pasted and assigned as a new json object.

i.e.

```
iris[1:38, ] %>% toJSON(.) %>% dput(.)

# structure("[{\"Sepal.Length\":5.1,\"Sepal.Width\":3.5,\"Petal.Length\":1.4,\"Petal.Width\":0.2,\"Species\":\"setosa\"},
# etc

new_json_object <- structure("[{\"Sepal.Length\":5.1,\"Sepal.Width\":3.5,\"Petal.Length\":1.4,\"Petal.Width\":0.2,\"Species\":\"setosa\"},
# This works
```

But if the same is done for more than the first 38 rows (e.g. `iris[1:39, ]`, and the resulting output copy/pasted and assigned as a new json object, the R console expects more input (i.e. it doesn't assign)

```
iris[1:39, ] %>% toJSON(.) %>% dput(.)
# structure("[{\"Sepal.Length\":5.1,\"Sepal.Width\":3.5,\"Petal.Length\":1.4,\"Petal.Width\":0.2,\"Species\":\"setosa\"},

new_json_object <- structure("[{\"Sepal.Length\":5.1,\"Sepal.Width\":3.5,\"Petal.Length\":1.4,\"Petal.Width\":0.2,\"Species\":\"setosa\"},
# etc
# This does not work
```

I am curious to know what is causing this behaviour. Is it a limit on how long a single R command can be, or is there an issue with either `toJSON()` or `dput()` ?

Comment: Hmmm..strange. `iris %>% toJSON %>% dput` works for me.

Comment: @RonakShah If you copy the output in your console and try to assign it, does it assign as expected or does it hang as though expecting more input?

Comment: yes, it expects more input (indicated by `+` on the console) as it seems it is expecting to close some brackets. But why do you need to this? Can you do `new_json_object <- iris %>% toJSON %>% dput` directly ?

Comment: Assignment works for me, using `toJSON` from all of `jsonlite`, `rjson` and `RJSONIO` packages.

Comment: @neilfws are you assigning via the clipboard (by copy/pasting the console output of `toJSON(iris) %>% dput` ? I tried on another laptop and it definitely doesn't work for me on either one. Both are using version 3.5.1

Comment: @RonakShah the `+` is what I'm trying to work out, as this is unexpected behaviour (in that either `dput()` is not correctly returning the code necessary to generate the json object, or something else is happening

Comment: @user5783745 I'm assigning as suggested in Ronak Shah's comment.

Comment: I get the same behaviour, and have narrowed it down to `iris[1:37,]` works, `iris[1:38 ]` and more rows doesn't.

Comment: @SymbolixAU interesting. Rows 37/38 seem somewhat arbitrary. I wonder if there's some limit being hit (perhaps in the length of a single line of code)

Comment: @SymbolixAU can you confirm the rows that work/don't work. Strangely, `iris[1:38,] %>% toJSON %>% dput` works for me, but `iris[1:39,] %>% toJSON %>% dput` doesn't

Comment: you're right, the fail point is `1:39`

Comment: I think you may be running into the limit of 4096-bytes for console commands: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc. Quote: "Command lines entered at the console are limited4 to about 4095 bytes (not characters)."

Comment: See also: https://community.rstudio.com/t/does-console-impose-an-upper-limit-on-the-length-of-strings/12872